# react-native run-android androidPath= {path to android folder}

Tags: android, react-native

is there any way I can run command "react-native run-android" specifying the path to the android folder because the android folder is not inside the root folder but depending on the desired package to build I have many android folders something like this.

```
./react-native-root/apps/app1/android                                          
./react-native-root/apps/app2/android                                         
./react-native-root/apps/app3/android
```

similarly for ios as well.

Comment: Are you tried to go specific android directory (which you want to run) and then apply this `./gradlew assembleDebug` in a command line and check what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

- Go to the android/ directory of your react-native project
- Create a file called local.properties and put the path of your sdk in it like this

  **sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk**